# Use variable from applied build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, git-submodules

How can I use a variable defined in an applied `build.gradle`?

Applied `build.gradle` (located unter `api/build.gradle`):

```
// api version
def apiVersion = '1.0'

// add dependencies
dependencies {
    // ...
}
```

Main `build.gradle` that should use the variable `apiVersion`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'api/build.gradle'

// set version
// causes Could not find property 'apiVerion' on root project ...
version = apiVersion + '-1.0'

// ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `def apiVersion = '1.0'` (which declares a local variable), use `ext.apiVersion = '1.0'` (which declares an extra property). The consuming side stays the same (i.e. don't use `ext.` when reading the property).